# Image conversion framework

Tags: image-processing, frameworks, image-conversion

Could someone recommend an existing image conversion framework. I need to convert virtually all image formats: raster and vector, ms office, pdf, psd etc. Color precision is a must.

Thank you.

(edited)

Any platform, any language, but Windows is preferred. This would be a backend, so client platform is irrelevant. 
I know I could find multiple frameworks to cover all the formats (already have), but idea is to have as few as possible. 
Color precision is important as it is an image review system.

Comment: Have you thought about breaking up the problem? Maybe one solution for image formats, another for ms office, another for pdf, etc.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information than that if you want a sensible answer... What platform/OS? What environment/languages are acceptable/appropriate? Is it a desktop or web-interface? Are raw photos to be included? Why is colour precision a must - and to what degree?

Comment: Perhaps the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site would be a better place for this?

Comment: You would definitely find a bunch of softwares to convert image formats (jpg->png, jpg->pdf etc.), but I doubt you'll find MS Office formats (.doc, .xls etc.) converted to an image ... It doesn't make sense at all.
Imagemagick is the most used and most reliable image manipulate software and it has a command-line tool, so you can use it with any programming language you want. Also, you can find libraries that make it way easier for you.

Answer (score 4):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is the most complete image conversion tool I know, it has lot's of features to modify all types of images. The software works in cli and is available for any platform.

You can also find a lot of help on [their forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php).

Comment: +1 for imagemagic, it's as simple as: `convert "e:/myimages/image.png" "e:/myimages/image.jpg"`

Comment: FYI for GhostScript, it's as simple as: 
`gs -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=$pageNum -sOutputFile=./output/image%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q test.pdf -c quit`

Comment: **PLUS:** compare the reported **performance** / quality numbers. That may impact a lot your pipe-line(d) mode of operation on large file-conversion project(s):

**Using `convert`** to convert from PDF to PNG, with 300 density:
it took **426 seconds** and 51mb

**Using `gs`** to convert from PDF to PNG, with 300 density:
it took **135 seconds** and  39mb disk space

Further time improvement by using jpeg:
**Using `gs`** to convert from PDF to JPEG with 300 density and 100% quality:
**took just 32 seconds and 153mb disk space**

Answer (score 1):

Building on your key requirements:

1. to use the framework on your back-end,
2. to get the framework with an un-compromised ColorManagement precision

test the server-side suitability of a `GhostScript` framework.

Moving your solution's neutral-format to a `PostScript` level will solve all your other conversion related requirements.

Once your image-review system architecture settles on `PostScript`, "The Lingua Franca" for professional TypeSetting, both the conversion issue and the ColorManagement issue get out of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ImageResizing](http://imageresizing.net/) if you can develeop on .net platform.
IMHO great piece of software!

Answer (score 0):

Use Imagemagick as it can convert nearly all image formats.

for more info refer below link

http://www.imagemagick.org/